# How to declare a natural number type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Due to some specific reasons, I need to use array indices in TypeScript, and they must comply with natural numbers (i.e., non-negative integers) to avoid potential errors in the program.

Could you please tell me how to declare a natural number type in TypeScript?

Comment: There is no such specific type in TypeScript.  You can possibly write a generic constraint that checks, but that would only work to catch literal numbers entered in code.   Or you could make a branded type alias but that wouldn't catch literal numbers well. Right now this is very broad because there's no example code in your question.  Could you please [edit] to provide a [mre] that demonstrates your use cases so that we have something tangible to work with and make suggestions for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no possibility to do that at the moment with some type, however, there are possible alternatives:

1. Manually define the type:

```
type NaturalNumber = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 ... how much you need
```

2. Generic type [PositiveInteger](https://github.com/KamilHs/type-samurai/blob/main/src/number.d.ts?plain=1#L21):

```
type Integer<T extends number> = `${T}` extends `${string}.${string}`
  ? never
  : T;
type Positive<T extends number> = `${T}` extends `-${string}`
  ? never
  : T;
type PositiveInteger<T extends number> = Positive<Integer<T>>;
```

Testing:

```
type Case1 = PositiveInteger<12> // 12
type Case2 = PositiveInteger<12.4> // never
type Case3 = PositiveInteger<-12> // never
type Case4 = PositiveInteger<-12.4> // never
```

3. Generate a range between 0 and 999. We can use a recursive utility type that will give us integers between 0 and 999 included. The 999 is not a magic number, the compiler's depth limit is 1000, that's why we can't go beyond this.

```
type Range<Arr extends number[] = []> = Arr['length'] extends 999
  ? Arr[number]
  : Range<[...Arr, Arr['length']]>;
```

Testing:

```
// 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35 | 36 | 37 | 38 | 39 | 40 | 41 | 42 | ... 955 more ... | 998
type NaturalNumber = Range;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I will refer to the provided solution.

Comment: I really would have preferred to see a use case here, since actual code will probably hit issues with any of these approaches, such as [weirdness with unions of literals](https://tsplay.dev/NBVb4N).

Comment: @jcalz I think it is still better than nothing. It's clear that there is an adequate way to type check operations over the literals and the only use cases that I see are using it for defining keys or passing some argument to function, probably representing an index for array

Comment: I'm not implying the answer should be removed or anything, I just think there are lots of caveats and without use cases presented in the question it's not clear if this will actually address them (or the use cases of future readers either)

Comment: agree, if the author adds the use cases I will try to address them

Answer (score -1):

You can declare a number in TypeScript by doing the following:

```
let num:number = 123;
```

Comment: This is not solving the problem. I can easily do `let num: number = -123`